# Columns with mixed data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a set of data files that contain three different data set seach. These data sets are ordered as separate tables, each with its own columns. The data sets do not have a fixed length (i.e. rows).

I'm looking for a way to "clean" up the data and pour it into a new dataframe which will collect all three data sets (and will contain all of their columns, concatenated).

So basically what I've been trying to do is read each column header then pour its data into the corresponding column in the dataframe I created. However, the new column gets "fed" with all of the original column's data until the end of the file (including wrong data from the 2 data sets below the first).

Can someone advise on how to approach this issue?

Thanks!

e.g. I have a file that looks like this:

```
Column_Header A | Column_Header B | Column_Header C
Data1           | Data 2          | Data 3
Column_Header D | Column_Header E | Column_Header F
Data 4          | Data 5          | Data 6
```

And need the data frame to look like this

```
Column_Header A | Column_Header B| Column_Header C | Column_Header D | Column_Header E| Column_Header F
Data1           | Data2          | Data3           |                 |                |
                |                |                 | Data4           | Data5          |Data6
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
# Gather the files
files = [file for file in os.listdir('C:/Users/user/Downloads/Inventory data/Raw')]

# Create dataframe
all_files_data = pd.DataFrame()

# Add file data to dataframe
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Inventory data/Raw/"+file)
    all_files_data = pd.concat([all_files_data, df])

# Add columns to dataframe
all_files_data['Entry_Month'] = ''
all_files_data['Currency'] = ''
all_files_data['Notes'] = ''
```

However the values for entry month, currency and notes are jammed into the wrong columns (namely supplier name, purchase date and then value).
I need some way to create the separation and I've no idea how to approach this...

Comment: Hello and welcome StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far with your code?  We'll be in a better position to help you then.

Comment: @DanielWalker Thanks! Added.

Answer (score 0):

[read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has a parameter `nrows` and `skiprows`. The idea here is you first read n rows until the second header (nrows=n, skiprows=0), then the remaining m rows (nrows=m, skiprows=n). If you don't know this value in advance you can check each row individually until one contains the second header.

Afterwards you can combine the columns with the [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) function.